# Dynamic variable for binding

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, binding

I have a variable `myVar` which can take several values (1, 2, 3 etc...).
I have also many `s:Group` named `G1`, `G2`, `G3` etc...

How can I define dynamic variable name in `{}` to make binding ?

Something like :

```
<s:Group id="anotherGroup" height="{Group(this['G' + myVar]).height}" />
```

Thanks for help

Comment: How are you going to bind anotherGroup to multiple groups? Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

What you have done looks good to me. Here is an example of using variable as component id to access the property and use it for binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
  <fx:Script><![CDATA[
    [Bindable]
    private var myVar:int = 1;

    private function changeGroup_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(++myVar > 3)
        {
            myVar = 1;
        }        
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>
  <s:VGroup height="500" width="1000">
    <s:Group id="G1" height="25" width="100%" contentBackgroundColor="red">
        <s:BorderContainer borderColor="red" height="100%" width="100%">
            <s:Label text="Inside G1. Height: {G1.height}"/>
        </s:BorderContainer>
    </s:Group>
    <s:Group id="G2" height="50" width="100%" >
        <s:BorderContainer borderColor="blue" height="100%" width="100%">
            <s:Label text="Inside G2. Height: {G2.height}"/>
        </s:BorderContainer>
    </s:Group>
    <s:Group id="G3" height="75" width="100%">
        <s:BorderContainer borderColor="green" height="100%" width="100%">
            <s:Label text="Inside G3. Height: {G3.height}"/>
        </s:BorderContainer>
    </s:Group>
    <s:Group id="anotherGroup" height="{(this['G'+myVar] as Group).height}" width="100%">
        <s:BorderContainer borderColor="yellow" height="100%" width="100%">
            <s:Label text="Inside anotherGroup. Height: {anotherGroup.height}"/>
        </s:BorderContainer>
    </s:Group>
    <s:Button label="Change Group" click="changeGroup_clickHandler(event)"/>
  </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Yes it works like my method but in Flash Builder, I have a warning, I don't know why...